# Asp.Net Website Deployment with Single Page Assemblies

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web, assemblies

We have an asp.net website project i.e. we are publishing the website project with below options.

1. Allow this precompiled site to be updatable
2. Use fixed naming and single page assemblies

Please read this [precompilation article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx) for an overview.

Asp.net state management is in-process i.e. we do not use a state service or sql server for state.

To avoid issues as losing session state, we typically do production deployments after business hours (website is not used after business hours).

I'd like to know the effect on following file deployments on session state:

1. web config update: The application pool restarts and session state is lost. So web config updates have to be done after business hours.
2. individual page dll update: I'm not sure about this. How does this affect session state? I know that the pages' ViewStates will not be affected. **Update: I tested locally and Session state is lost on page dll update.**

Comment: What is your biggest concern?  Why not try testing things out locally?

Comment: In general, I'd like to know of side-effects. In particular, if I can do production deployments without any side-effects like session loss during business hours.

Comment: tested locally and found my answer. updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear
Can you be more specific 
I assume that you asked what happens to session when i deploy my site 
well session will expires if you update any dll if a user was connected to you site meanwhile you deployed your session will expires. for example you are saving userid in session then it will not be available

Comment: Yes, I want to know effect on Session state (application pool). Are you sure about it that when a page dll is changed, the Session would be lost? Can you refer me to a link.